# PHP RegEx preg_match_all Reiterate Matched Words Before the Current Match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the following RegEx code

```
$str = 'word1 word2 word3 keyword word4 word5 word6 keyword word7 word8 word9 word10';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/(\w* ){1,3}keyword( \w*){1,3}/u', $str, $matches);
```

I expect the matches to include:

> word1 word2 word3 keyword word4 word5 word6

> word4 word5 word6 keyword word7 word8 word9

But in reality, I'm getting these:

> word1 word2 word3 keyword word4 word5 word6

> keyword word7 word8 word9

In other words, the second match is cropped because of the 1st match.

Here's a test:
https://regex101.com/r/EPp14b/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to cross the word `keyword`, you might use a negative lookahead when repeating 1-3 words to assert that they are not the keyword.

After the match, you can use a positive lookahead assertion with a capture group, matching 1-3 words which are again not the `keyword`

The sentence will be a concatenation of the full match and group 1.

```
(?<!\S)(?:(?!keyword\b)\w+\h+){1,3}keyword\b(?=((?:\h+(?!keyword\b)\w+){1,3}))
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitspace boundary to the left
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!keyword\b)\w+\h+` Negative lookahead, match a word and whitespaces if it is not `keyword`
- `){1,3}` Close non capture group and repeat 1-3 times
- `keyword\b` Match `keyword`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `(?:\h+(?!keyword\b)\w+){1,3}` Match 1-3 words that do not start with `keyword`
  - `)` Close group 1
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rvbz3j/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/aa2oL)

```
$re = '/(?<!\S)((?:(?!keyword\b)\w+\h+){1,3}keyword\b)(?=((?:\h+(?!keyword\b)\w+){1,3}))/u';

$strings = [
    "word1 word2 word3 keyword word4 word5 word6 keyword word7 word8 word9 word10",
    "word2 keyword word4 word5 word6 keyword word7 word8",
    "word2 word3 keyword word4 word5 word6 keyword word7 keyword word10",
];

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    $matches = array_map(function($m) {
        return $m[1] . $m[2];
    }, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => word1 word2 word3 keyword word4 word5 word6
    [1] => word4 word5 word6 keyword word7 word8 word9
)
Array
(
    [0] => word2 keyword word4 word5 word6
    [1] => word4 word5 word6 keyword word7 word8
)
Array
(
    [0] => word2 word3 keyword word4 word5 word6
    [1] => word4 word5 word6 keyword word7
    [2] => word7 keyword word10
)
```

Comment: Great use of look arounds ++

Comment: Great! I appreciate the time you spent explaining all this.
I have a further question on it though. What if I wanted to include some kinds of plurals for the keyword? I mean, currently it only matches the singular form. But what if I wanted it to match the plural, the past, and possibly other forms with other suffixes and affixes of the keyword?

Comment: @user12281887 You are welcome. If you want to list multiple words, you can use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) using `|` like `(?:word1|word2)`

Comment: Hmmm. That would be too much work, especially when the probabilities are almost infinite.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to put complete match in a capture group inside a lookahead to be able to get overlapped matches:

```sh
(?=((\b(?:\w+\h+){1,3}keyword)(?:\h+\w+){1,3}))(?2)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1P78m2/1)

**Code:**

```sh
$s = 'word1 word2 word3 keyword word4 word5 word6 keyword word7 word8 word9 word10';
$re = '/(?=((\b(?:\w+\h+){1,3}keyword)(?:\h+\w+){1,3}))(?2)/u';
preg_match_all($re, $s, $m);
print_r($m[1]);

/* Output
Array
(
    [0] => word1 word2 word3 keyword word4 word5 word6
    [1] => word4 word5 word6 keyword word7 word8 word9
)
*/
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?=`: Start lookahead

  - `(`: Start capture group #1

    - `(`: Start capture group #2

      - `\b`: Word boundary
      - `(?:\w+\h+){1,3}`: Match 1 to 3 words
      - `keyword`:
    - `)`: End capture group #2
    - `(?:\h+\w+){1,3}`: Match 1 to 3 words
  - `)`: End capture group #1
- `)`: End lookahead
- `(?2)`: Recurse capture group #2

Comment: It is very clever to recurse the second capture group to not capture it again in the lookahead. Definitely something to remember! ++

Comment: Thnaks for the other option.

Answer (score 0):

The whole part you need (keyword + words around) is inside a capture group (result) in a lookahead assertion, this way characters aren't consumed and can be part of an eventual next match later.
But to avoid to match the same keyword several time, you need to reach the position after this one, and consume all the characters until the keyword included. This is why I defined a group called *consume* and I used a reference to his content: `\g{consume}`.

```
$pattern = '~
\b
(?=
    (?<result>
        (?<consume>
           (?> \w+ \h+ ){0,3}?
           keyword \b
        )
        (?: \h+ (?! keyword \b ) \w+ ){0,3}
    )
) \g{consume}
~ux';
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/pFjlTZ/1)

With this pattern you don't have to reconstitute the result, all is stored in the named group *result*:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches['result']);
```